# Cypress 9.6.0 - response returned from cy.request has a body as ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, http, request, cypress

I'd like to access response body of request sent via `cy.request` inside custom command, but response's body turns out to be `ArrayBuffer` for some weird reason, but rest of the response is just fine. Here is code example:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('requestWrapped', ({ method, path, body }) => {
  const token = window.sessionStorage.getItem('x-csrf')

  cy.request({
    method,
    url: `${Cypress.env('backendUrl')}/${path}`,
    body,
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': token,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    },
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.body) // ArrayBuffer here
  })
})
```

And it's being called inside `it` block

```
cy.requestWrapped({
  method: 'POST',
  path: 'some/random/path',
  body: {
    name: xyz,
    id: 123-123,
  },
})
```

I also tried to use `cy.request` standalone inside the test, without any wrapper around - got same result

Any ideas what might went wrong there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a change in behavior from a previous Cypress version, or are you just asking how you can turn an `ArrayBuffer` into a string/JSON?

Comment: The issue is that instead of an `ArrayBuffer` I should be getting normal JSON format response (ofc during the test in the app request returns `JSON` format response and everything works - that is data is getting populated, in browser's network tab on that particular request response looks just as it should). I wonder why `cy.request` might transform body response into `ArrayBuffer`?

Answer (score 4):

This works, but I'm hoping someone posts a better solution:

```
cy.request({
 ...
}).then((response) => {
 const bodyString = Cypress.Blob.arrayBufferToBinaryString(response.body);
 const body = JSON.parse(bodyString);
 expect(body.amountOfMinutesIResearchedIt).to.equal(35);
})
```

Comment: it is accepted answer u save my day. i was stuck hole day.